# Single Sign On Between B2B and B2C Azure AD

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have application 1 that uses Azure AD B2B. User is logged in to the application 1. If the user is redirected from application 1 to application 2, I want the user to be automatically logged in to the application 2 as well.
Application 2 is using the AZure B2C AD.
Is that possible to achieve?
Thanks

Comment: question edited

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if the Azure AD B2B identity is federated, as an external or "social" identity, with the Azure AD B2C tenant.

An example of this identity federation is shown by [the Woodgrove Groceries sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/resources/samples/active-directory-external-identities-woodgrove-demo/) where a B2B identity has been integrated with a B2C tenant.